# What is the best way to automate a data connection between two Excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two workbooks, with two tables that I want to be in sync. Right now, I  have a VLOOKUP formula that requires the user to press Enter (inside the specific cell to update) and select the other file and the data is refreshed correctly. Is there a solution that involves a better formula or VBA solution?

**what I have so far:**

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,'C:\User\Desktop[xyz.xslm]Table'!B:E,2,FALSE)
```

**other info:** The two tables have the same column and row structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your version of Excel. Here is a solution that works in Excel 2016:
In the workbook with the VLOOKUP, click the Data tab, click Edit links. At bottom left there is a button, Startup Prompt. There you can select automatic update without prompting the user. You don't even have to open the second workbook in order to sync.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d), you should combine data from multiple data sources with Power Query (feature in Excel). It is an ETL(Extract-Transform-Load) tool extremely powerful.